# Need help blinking a led continuously?

Tags: pi-3, python-3, tutorial

I'm new to Python and just go this Raspberry Pi, and need help blinking this led. I have got it to where the LED will blink once( Turn on for a second, then turn off). I need some help so when I hit run the LED will blink continuously.

Here is my code that I have so far -

```
#blink.py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(4, True)
time.sleep(.5)
GPIO.output(4, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the on/off part of the code in an endless loop:

```
#blink.py
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(4, True)
    time.sleep(.5)
    GPIO.output(4, False)
    time.sleep(.5)
```